# How do you get a list from complex active record has_many involved from a subset of downstream objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm having a hard time getting a list of the games involved from a hierarchical parent relationship when multiple foreign keys are implemented on a relationship in the middle.

Given League Object `NFC`, find all of its Game objects `[G1,G3,G4]`

```rb
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  name         :string
class League
  has_many :teams
  # has_many :games, :through => :teams (Is there some way to do this?)
end

#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  team_name    :string
#  league_id :integer
class Team
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :home_games, :foreign_key => team_a_id, :source => :game
  has_many :away_games, :foreign_key => team_b_id, :source => :game
end

#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  game_name            :string
#  team_a_id :integer          not null
#  team_b_id :integer          not null
class Game
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => Team
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => Team
end
```

Data Examples:

```
LEAGUE - TEAM - GAME 
---------------------------------
AFC - 
        PATRIOTS - 
                 Home       Away   
               G1(PATRIOTS vs DALLAS)
               G2(PATRIOTS vs PITTSBURG)
        PITTSBURG - 
               G2(PATRIOTS vs PITTSBURG)
NFC - 
        DALLAS - 
               G1(PATRIOTS vs DALLAS)
               G3(DALLAS vs GREENBAY)
               G4(DALLAS vs SEATTLE)
        GREENBAY
               G3(DALLAS vs GREENBAY)
        SEATTLE
               G4(DALLAS vs SEATTLE)
```

The answer will contain a Rails 4 compliant answer. Special consideration may be awarded to a RAILS 5 answer if the Rails 4 alternative is very inefficient.

```rb
nfc = League.where(name: 'NFC').first
# <answer>
puts nfc.games 
##  array containing objects [G1,G2,G3]
```

The challenge Im having with is the `home_team` / `away_team` and combining data from the foreign keys.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to clarify your question. You seem to ask two separate things: How to “get a list of the leagues involved from a subset of games” and how to “Find all games that have NFC teams”. You don't explain what criteria makes a Team “NFC”, and instead show an example of querying for Leagues named “NFC”.

Comment: Hopefully its been clarified.

Comment: It would be much simpler to just list a team's games in a single association, then indicate `home` as a boolean value.  Ie: Team `has_many :games` -- Home games are `games.where(home: true)`

Comment: understand hold: Going back to code to get relevant data set problem

Comment: I see what your issue is. On mobile now, but I can answer shortly when I'm back at my computer. Question: is Rails 5 an option, or are you locked to 4?

Comment: @meagar He doesn't have 'games' defined as a relationship on Team, so that won't work as-is.

Comment: @coreyward You're right, my bad. I removed the bounty prior to closing, I can't restore it but I'll offer up a bounty of my own.

Comment: Ill put back the bounty / award it to answer 200 pts

Comment: @shadowbq Is the data as presented accurate? Does a team from the AFC really participate in games in the NFC? For example, Patriots, a team in the AFC, has games in the NFC league.

Comment: Yes the data is accurate.AFC plays NFC in game #1.  Teams have games that play across the leagues. The solution needs to find all games involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give an answer,
because the first solution by @meagar
requires two SQL queries instead of one (also, isn't that a SQL syntax error if a league has no teams?),
and the second solution will contain duplicate Game instances
if both teams were from the same league.

In general I try to avoid joins in my reusable scopes,
since they force the query into a certain "shape".
So I would write something like this:

```
class Game
  # ...
  scope :for_league, ->(league_id) {
    where(<<-EOQ, league_id)
      EXISTS (SELECT  1
              FROM    teams t
              WHERE   t.id IN (games.team_a_id, games.team_b_id)
              AND     t.league_id = ?)
    EOQ
  }
  # ...
end
```

This SQL technique is called a "correlated sub-query" by the way. I admit it looks strange the first time you see it, but it is a pretty normal thing to do. You can see that the subquery "reaches out" to reference `games`. Your database should have no problem optimizing it (given indexes on your foreign keys of course), but conceptually speaking it runs the subquery once per row in the `games` table.

Comment: This would be a better solution if it didn't require hardcoding table and attribute names into a SQL literal. Arel makes it possible to create more flexible scopes that can be reused without brittle hardcoding of attributes.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to define a `games` method on `League` that finds all of the games where either foreign key points to one of its teams:

```
class League

  has_many :teams


  def games
    Game.where('team_a_id in (:ids) or team_b_id in(:ids)', ids: teams.pluck(:id))
  end
end
```

You can accomplish the same thing with a `join`:

```
Game.joins('inner join teams on teams.id = games.team_a_id or teams.id = games.team_b_id').where('teams.league_id = ?', id)
```

Comment: can you rewrite this as scope lambda rocket

Comment: Can you award yourself or cancel the bounty .. If you can't and need to wait for it to lapse, I will come back in 7 days and attempt to replace the bounty and award it to you. (Not alot of exp with bounties sorry)

Comment: @shadowbq I'd really encourage you to look at [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41885374/229044). I'm not enough of an SQL guru to gauge it's performance relative to mine, but he's definitely correct in that mine may return duplicate teams.